# sql: filter datetime columns based on given intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am facing an issue related to filtering out events that were active during a certain time interval i.e. 7 to 9

```
EventId             StartTime                       EndTime            
18   2013-04-11 16:33:11.735342100   2013-04-11 17:16:47.976164100  
19   2013-04-10 16:33:46.575337300   2013-04-11 18:10:08.428443900  
20   2013-04-10 17:17:04.033083300   2013-04-11 18:10:13.907757900  
21   2013-04-11 00:10:24.293352100   2013-04-11 18:45:17.754240800  
23   2013-04-11 01:11:20.278558900   2013-04-11 18:45:00.435247300  
25   2013-04-15 09:42:22.549026700   2013-04-15 23:54:33.389964300  
26   2013-04-16 07:42:24.588807700   2013-04-16 17:42:41.077751300  
28   2013-04-19 16:51:22.699240800   2013-04-19 18:39:03.167468100  
31   2013-04-19 18:30:56.891621300   2013-04-19 19:42:50.418640200  
17   2013-04-20 16:07:07.327879000   2013-04-20 22:17:17.783053600
```

I want to filter out those events that were active during 7-9am including events that start at 8, I used simple time comparison and it works as intended, but given the data-set it fails to get some of the results e.g event Id `20`

```
20   2018-05-10 17:17:04.033083300   2018-05-11 18:10:13.907757900
```

as this event is active in the time interval 7-9 next day, but i am unable to get it, because of the date change.

Comment: . . This is quite complicated because your periods span days.

Comment: What did you try up until now? Can you provide the SQL?

Comment: I think I'd use a calendar table (or equivalent) to ask if every day at 7 or 9, the calendar table date was between the start and end date..

Comment: I am pretty sure it can be done with sufficient where-criteria.

Comment: When you say "filter out" do you actually mean "filter in" ? To me "filter out" means "remove from the resultset" - do you want to see events between 7 and 9,or do you want to see everything other than events between 7 and 9

Comment: @CaiusJard , i want to see events between 7-9

Comment: OK, please don't use the phrase "filter out" to indicate that infuture; try "filter to just" or "show only rows with" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this logic detects any overlap:

```
where -- more than one day, then automatic
      endTime > dateadd(day, 1, startTime) or
      ( -- same day
       convert(date, endTime) = convert(date, startTime) and
       datepart(hour, startTime) < 9 and
       datepart(hour, endTime >= 7
      ) or
      ( -- next day
       convert(date, endTime) = dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, startTime)) and
       datepart(hour, startTime) < 9 or
       datepart(hour, endTime >= 7
      )
```

Note that this detects *any* overlap with the time period, not a full overlap.

EDIT:

For a full overlap:

```
where -- more than one day, then automatic
      endTime > dateadd(day, 1, startTime) or
      ( -- same day
       convert(date, endTime) = convert(date, startTime) and
       convert(time, startTime) <= '07:00:00' and
       convert(time, endTime) >= '09:00:00'
      ) or
      ( -- next day
       convert(time, startTime) <= '07:00:00' or
       convert(time, endTime) >= '09:00:00'
      )
```

Comment: your ans works for me but, what do you mean by any overlap, why does it do so, Also, i think it will skip the events that start at 8?

Comment: @M_S_N . . . The first query is *any* point in time during 7-9.  I misunderstood your sentence about 8:00 a.m. The second query is for the *entire* time period.

Comment: shouldn't 2nd query be like this `( -- next day
      convert(date, LogoutTime) > convert(date, LoginTime) and
       convert(time, LoginTime) <= '07:00:00' and
       convert(time, LogoutTime) >= '09:00:00'
      )`

Comment: I am actually trying to get events active during this time period `7,8,9`, so events which start before 7,8 or during this time and end after 9

Comment: @M_S_N . . . It is probably a good idea to be explicit.  I updated the answer.